# After installation of Haskell: Haskell works, but isn't attainable in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, haskell

I installed Haskell for the use of TidalCycles on Mac / 10.14.6 
TidalCycles works fine, so Haskell should to work too.
However, after entering 'ghci' in the terminal, the following message appears

-bash: ghci: command not found

Do I have to set a correct path (e.g. .bashrc)? And if so, where to?

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how you installed Haskell.

The recommended way to install Haskell on a Mac according to TidalCycles [documentation](https://tidalcycles.org/index.php/MacOS_installation) is to install `ghcup` using this command:

```
curl https://get-ghcup.haskell.org -sSf | sh
```

If you install Haskell this way the [install script](https://get-ghcup.haskell.org) will ask you to add a line to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` that should take care of adding everything you need to your `$PATH`.

*If you installed Haskell in a different way you can update the question to reflect that and I will update my answer.*

If you want to fix things manually you can try if running this makes `ghci` available:

```bsh
. "$HOME/.ghcup/env"
```

If that's the case you can make `ghci` available permanently by adding 
`. $HOME/.ghcup/env`
to the appropriate dotfile (`.bashrc` or `.bash_profle`)

[This blog post](https://chekkan.com/install-haskell-platform-on-mac/) provides a more detailed tutorial on how to install Haskell and on how to make sure that all the executables are in your `$PATH`.